# Deployment error on Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat

I'm deploying a mavenize web project in Eclipse Mars, JDK 1.7 and Tomcat 6

This the exceptions

```
    06/01/2016 11:30:06,962 ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:177) Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ajaxFacade' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-ajax.xml]: Can't resolve reference to bean 'posanetService' while setting property 'posanetService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.tunisiana.posanet.service.impl.DefaultPosanetService#19ca9bb' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-service.xml]: Can't resolve reference to bean 'invoiceService' while setting property 'invoiceService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.support.RegexpMethodPointcutAdvisor#46f6ad' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-service.xml]: Can't resolve reference to bean 'generatePaymentReferenceAdvice' while setting property 'advice'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'threadlocalTargetSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-common.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'targetClass' of bean class [org.springframework.aop.target.ThreadLocalTargetSource]: Bean property 'targetClass' is not writable or has an invalid setter method: Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.tunisiana.posanet.service.impl.DefaultPosanetService#19ca9bb' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-service.xml]: Can't resolve reference to bean 'invoiceService' while setting property 'invoiceService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.support.RegexpMethodPointcutAdvisor#46f6ad' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-service.xml]: Can't resolve reference to bean 'generatePaymentReferenceAdvice' while setting property 'advice'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'threadlocalTargetSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-common.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'targetClass' of bean class [org.springframework.aop.target.ThreadLocalTargetSource]: Bean property 'targetClass' is not writable or has an invalid setter method: Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.support.RegexpMethodPointcutAdvisor#46f6ad' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-service.xml]: Can't resolve reference to bean 'generatePaymentReferenceAdvice' while setting property 'advice'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'threadlocalTargetSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-common.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'targetClass' of bean class [org.springframework.aop.target.ThreadLocalTargetSource]: Bean property 'targetClass' is not writable or has an invalid setter method: Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'threadlocalTargetSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-common.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'targetClass' of bean class [org.springframework.aop.target.ThreadLocalTargetSource]: Bean property 'targetClass' is not writable or has an invalid setter method: Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'targetClass' of bean class [org.springframework.aop.target.ThreadLocalTargetSource]: Bean property 'targetClass' is not writable or has an invalid setter method: Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the cglib.jar and asm.jar to your class path (or dependencies in pom.xml)

Comment: hi @zied, i didnt found the file !

Comment: All the comments were deleted

Comment: thnx @zied sorry but i didn't understand : why u didn't send me the file .war generated ? :o because this folder is not considered like a project that i can import

Comment: In fact, I deployed the war on tomcat thenI made my changes to the folder directly.
 for that I don't have a new war.

Comment: So what can i do with that ? I suppose that i can't even deploy it in Tomcat because i need the .war too no ?

Comment: No, you can, put the folder under webapps and restart tomcat

Comment: could you post the caused exception, like this i can't see

Comment: you have a log file under D:\, could you post the caused exception?

Comment: so i got this : `Grave: One or more listeners failed to start. Full détails will be found in appropriate container log file` also : `Erreur de démarrage du contexte [posanet...] suite aux erreurs prédcédentes`.  also : `Grave : The web application posa registred the JDBC driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.oracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistred ` and finally `Grave : the web app has started thread named [FileWatchdog] but failed to stop it`

Comment: in apllicationContext-common.xml file, remove `<property name="targetClass"    value="com.tunisiana.posanet.model.externalTransaction.ExternalTransactionRequest" />`

Comment: I re Edit @zied , sorry for taking ur time my friend :( Is it normal that i got that exceptions meanwhile u didn't get them ?

Comment: It is quite normal, I didn't have this problem beacuase I stopped while connecting to the database. Since you do not have a connection problem, so you go to the next stages. You are welcome

Comment: But i configured ur folder and deploy it in Tomcat, unless i began yesterday with deleting some jars like u said but without `log4j.jar` my .war won't be deployed so i added him. Still got exceptions... And i'm not a pro developer and i'm frustrated about that. So tell me what can i do plz ...

Comment: replace 
`<property name="targetClass"
     value="com.tunisiana.posanet.model.externalTransaction.ExternalTransactionRequest" />`
   by
`<property name="targetClass">
        <value type="java.lang.Class">com.tunisiana.posanet.model.externalTransaction.ExternalTransactionRequest</value>
    </property>`

Comment: I think you'll still have problems that are not related to the initial problem. this is my email landolsi.zied@gmail.com, we can chat.

Comment: Thnx i sent u on hangout